# Getting Age using regular expression

Tags: python, regex

```
year="Year Of Birth (Age): 1953 (68)"
```

How do you extract only the numerical age in the brackets using regular expressions?
The above string is part of a bigger string that I need to extract data from so can't share the entire string.

I have tried the following code :

```
y = re.findall(r'(Age):\s[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\s\(([0-9[0-9])', year)
```

Need some help.

Comment: `re.findall('\(\d+\)', year)`

Comment: What happens when you run your code? What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: `re.findall(r"\(Age\): \d{4} \((\d+)\)", year)`

Comment: `re.findall('\((\d+)\)', year)` will only extract the number

Comment: Escape the parentheses around `Age`

Comment: I suggest using https://regex101.com/ to test and debug your regex. You will quickly see the problem is as Pranav says. The rest of the comments here are just noise.

Answer (score 2):

You can look lookbehind assertion, to get the number in parenthesis only if there is `(Age)` string before it, more specifically, only if it is preceded by the string that matches the pattern `\(Age\):\s\d{4}\s`:

```py
>>> re.findall('(?<=\(Age\):\s\d{4}\s)\((\d+)\)', year)
['68']
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you can do it this way, It depends if your text follow the following pattern

> (Age): 1953 (68)

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'\(Age\):\s\d{4}\s\(?P<age>\d+\)')
m = p.search("Year Of Birth (Age): 1953 (68)")
m.group("age")
```